# the inequality $\ln(e + 2^p x) \le (p+1) \ln (e+x) \quad (x,p>0)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Hoping for suggestions regarding a proof. The function $f_p(x) = (p+1) \ln(e+x) - \ln (e+ 2^p x)$ has $f_p(0)=p>0$ and a critical point at $x_0 = \frac{e[2^p-(p+1)]}{p 2^p}$, but $f_p(x_0)$ is messy. By monotonicity the inequality can be written without logarithms, but at the expense of changing $p+1$ into an exponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can power each side of the inequality by $e$:
$$e + 2^px \leq (e+x)^{p+1} = e^{p+1} + e^px + x^{p+1} + \epsilon, \epsilon \geq 0$$

In the above the equality comes from the general binomial theorem for expansion of the $(e+x)^{p+1}$.
As we know $e^{p} > 2^p$ for  $p>0$, the proof is completed.